# What is wrong with my SQL SELECT query?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get all info from table `a`, but get error:

> ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier.

This is my query:

```
SELECT a
FROM FORMS a,
     APPLICATIONS b
WHERE b.APPLICATION_ID = a.APPLICATION_ID
  AND a.APPLICATION_ID = 14980
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Do you have column with name "a" in any of this tables? Or you mean that you want to output alll columns from table FORMS? If so, you should use `SELECT a.*`

Comment: @Tatiana I am trying to get all columns from FORMS.

Comment: @Tatiana Thank you! I am new in SQL queries.

Comment: Why do you join APPLICATIONS without selecting any of its columns?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @jarlh, inner joins are useful even if you don't need any data from the joined table - they (most usefully) limit the results from the first table by those that have a corresponding record in the second table, and (less usefully) multiply the number of results by the number of matching rows in the second table. (Obviously, the join can be logically eliminated if there is an appropriate referential constraint and a unique constraint on `b.APPLICATION_ID`.)

Comment: @JeffreyKemp, sorry, I was just trying to get OP think one more time what's going on. Joining a table without selecting can be useful, but it's not lesson one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM FORMS a, APPLICATIONS b 
WHERE b.APPLICATION_ID = a.APPLICATION_ID AND a.APPLICATION_ID = 14980;
```

And better to use new syntax:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM FORMS a JOIN APPLICATIONS b ON b.APPLICATION_ID = a.APPLICATION_ID 
WHERE a.APPLICATION_ID = 14980;
```

Comment: pity it didn't explicitly use **INNER** JOIN though